# Find out What Am I

Tags: riddle

I am very prestigious..

Although not as prestigious as my elder brother.

U don't see me often. once in a few years only.

A small nation has conquered me for several years.

Yet, I am back this year again.

Although, I didn't like my entry this time

Yet, it was all minuscule after a bigger exit happened.

I am still continuing now, although not for a long time.

I will be back again in a few years time, with a different conqueror(Maybe)..

Till then, try to guess What Am I??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it

> UEFA Euro 2016

I am very prestigious..

Although not as prestigious as my elder brother.

> FIFA Cup

U don't see me often. once in a few years only.

> once in four years

A small nation has conquered me for several years.

> Germany and Spain each have won three titles

Yet, I am back this year again.

am still continuing now, although not for a long time.

> this years competition is from June 10 to July 10

Although, I didn't like my entry this time

Yet, it was all minuscule after a bigger exit happened.

> Don't have any idea about this, maybe referring to this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_at_UEFA_Euro_2016

I will be back again in a few years time, with a different conqueror(Maybe)..

> Euro 2020

Comment: "Although, I didn't like my entry this time

Yet, it was all minuscule after a bigger exit happened."  - BREXIT maybe?

Comment: perfect!!+1  Yeah... it was related to violence and BREXIT...